# warning coming during compilation

Tags: c, optimization

Warning comes in following given set of code, that warning affects during the compilation of code. Here 3 sets of code is given in all set of code, warning is coming.

First:

```
unsigned long Get_TestVal(unsigned int B_Index) 
{
     unsigned long val = 0;
     if((B_Index >= 0) && (B_Index < 16)) // condition is always true: warning came 
           val = 1;
     else if((B_Index >= 16) && (B_Index < 32))
         val = 2;
    .....
    return (val);
}
```

Second:

```
for(i =0 ; i < 2; i++)
{
    if((Buffer[i] >= 0)  && (Buffer[i]<= 9) ) // condition is always true: warning came 
    {
            Buffer[i] = Buffer[i] + 48;
    }
}
```

Third:

```
 if(val < 0)// condition is always false :warning came
    {
        flag = HMP_LO;                      
    }
```

Comment: i think its because `unsigned`

Comment: We can't help you for the second code as you've not provided enough information. So,post the declaration of `Buffer`.

Comment: for test1: This part of the expression: 'if((B_Index >= 0) '  is always true, because B_Index is unsigned, so B_Index is ALWAYS is >= 0  You can fix the problem by removing that first comparison from the 'if' statement

Comment: for test2: this part of the expression 'if((Buffer[i] >= 0)' (although we cannot be sure) is always true because Buffer[] is unsigned so Buffer[i] must ALWAYS be >= 0

Comment: for test3: (although we cannot be sure) is always false because val is unsigned so val must ALWAYS be >= 0

Answer (score 2):

Since both `B_Index` and `val`  are of type `unsigned long`, they will (by definition) never be less than zero (i.e. negative). That's what the warning is telling you for the first and last cases.

You don't show the declaration of  `Buffer`, so it's hard to help with that.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the data type of `B_Index`. It says `unsigned int` which guarantees a value of `>= 0` all the time [even after overflow]. That's why the warning  is there for the code `if((B_Index >= 0)...`.

Same with `unsigned long val` and `if(val < 0)` being always *FALSE*.

Lastly, I think we can safely *assume*, in case of `if((Buffer[i] >= 0)`, `Buffer` is of `unsigned` data type and the reason behind the warning is same as the first case.

***Solution:*** You can safely remove those particular condition checks.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, B_Index is of type `unsigned int` and therefore B_Index is always greater than or equal to 0.

In the second and third examples, you do not specify a type for `Buffer[i]` or `val`, but I assume a similar condition holds.

Answer (score 0):

1) The warning is generated by the condition `B_Index >= 0`, you can safely remove it as long as you are using `unsigned`.

2) Same here, assuming Buffer is an array-like of `unsigned`, the warning is generated by the condition `Buffer[i] >= 0`, you can safely remove it as long as you are using `unsigned`.

3) Same principle here. The warning is generated by `val < 0`, if you expect negative numbers you shouldn't be using `unsigned`.

Extra) You should be testing against `unsigned` literals, as in: `index == 1u`. The `u` at the end tells the compiler that the literal should be an `unsigned`.